# Sql select max id from table

Tags: php, sql, select, insert, max

I want to get the Max userID from tblLogin and add 1 
This value i want to put into a string to insert into the table

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO tblLogin (Gebruikersnaam, Wachtwoord, UserID)
VALUES ('$_POST[gebruikersnaam]','$_POST[wachtwoord]', 'SELECT MAX(tblLogin.UserID) FROM tblLogin')";
```

I want to insert another row with the UserID then being the max one (5) + 1 so 6 
**However if i try this with the code i have now
it just adds 1 instead of 6**

It looks like it takes the value as 0 and i don't know why.

The 'Gebruikersnaam' (it's dutch :p) and 'Wachtwoord' are being inserted fine.
Only the UserID gives an issue.

Help.

Answer (score 2):

You can set UserID field to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Thereafter you don't need to pass `USerID` value in your insert query.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to to increase it everytime then you should set it to auto increment.
otherwise you can try like this:

```
 $sql2="INSERT INTO tblLogin 
   (Gebruikersnaam, Wachtwoord, UserID)
   VALUES ('$_POST[gebruikersnaam]','$_POST[wachtwoord]',
   (SELECT 1+MAX(tblLogin.UserID) FROM tblLogin)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO tblLogin (Gebruikersnaam, Wachtwoord, UserID)
       SELECT '$_POST[gebruikersnaam]','$_POST[wachtwoord]', MAX(tblLogin.UserID) 
       FROM tblLogin";
```